# How can I skip indexing a specific property, but still retrieve its contents when querying in Elasticsearch and NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Given this index-model class:

```cs
public class ProductIndexModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public JObject DynamicContent { get; set; }
}
```

I am struggling to do the following:

- store the entire object in Elasticsearch
- index all properties, *except* `DynamicContent` property
- upon querying, retrieve the entire object (including `DynamicContent` prop)

My reason for not indexing `DynamicContent` property is, that it's a json-blob, where occasionally there will be clashes between property-paths, that are of different types (e.g. object vs string, int vs string, and so on). For example, trying to index path /dynamiccontent.id with 2 objects, where value is respectively of type int and string might give me:

> error: Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "failed to parse
>   [dynamiccontent.id]" CausedBy: Type: json_parse_exception Reason:
>   "Current token (START_OBJECT) not numeric, can not use numeric value
>   accessors

I create the index in this way:

```cs
var createIndexResponse = await _elasticClient.CreateIndexAsync(indexName, c => c
    .InitializeUsing(settingsState)
    .Mappings(ms => ms
        .Map<ProductIndexModel>(m => m
            .AutoMap()
        )
    )
);
```

Where `settingsState` is of type `Nest.IndexState` with some tokenizers and more, that is irrelevant to the question.

```cs
ISearchRequest SearchRequest(SearchDescriptor<ProductIndexModel> x) => x
    .Index(indexName)
    .Query(q => q.Bool(bq => bq.Filter(filters)))
    .From(filter.Offset)
    .Size(filter.PageSize)
;

var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<ProductIndexModel>(SearchRequest);
```

Where `filters` is a dynamically constructed generic list of filters to reduce results by.

So I want to keep `DynamicContent` un-indexed, but still be able to get its (raw) contents when querying.

I have tried to annotate `DynamicContent` with the `Nest.IgnoreAttribute` which leaves it out entirely, thus resulting in a null value when retrieving. Any suggestions as to how to just "store" the value, but not index it, using NEST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `DynamicContent` is a Json.NET `JObject` type, if you're using NEST 6.x, you will need to [hook up the `JsonNetSerializer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) to be able to correctly index an instance of `JObject`.

Once this serializer is hooked up, you can attribute the model with `[Object(Enabled = false)]`, which sets [`enabled=false` for the field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html), meaning the property is persisted in `_source` but not parsed or indexed.

With `JObject` in particular, NEST's automapping (which is needed to take the attribute into account when mapping) will generate a large `"properties"` object for `JObject` which is wholly unneccessary, since the field will not be parsed or indexed. In this particular case, fluent mapping would be a better choice than attribute mapping. Here's an example:

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "default_index";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, JsonNetSerializer.Default)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
        .DefaultTypeName("_doc");

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<ProductIndexModel>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap() // <-- automap
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Object<JObject>(o => o
                        .Name(n => n.DynamicContent) <-- override the automap inferred mapping for DynamicContent
                        .Enabled(false)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var indexResponse = client.Index(new ProductIndexModel
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Name = "foo",
        DynamicContent = new JObject 
        {
            { "prop1", "value1" },
            { "prop2", new JArray(1, 2, 3, 4) }
        }
    }, i => i.Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor));

    var searchResponse = client.Search<ProductIndexModel>(s => s
        .MatchAll()
    );
}

public class ProductIndexModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Object(Enabled = false)]
    public JObject DynamicContent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Russ, thank you so much for taking time to write such a great and detailed answer! You helped me solve the problem indeed - the `Enabled` flag was a bit cryptic to me, and then also I had cooked me up some swiss-cheese issues in my attemps, but your answer brought me back on track.

One last thing: would it be possible when creating the index with Nest to override the Automap() with a mapping defined in JSON as when using the REST Api https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html instead of the fluent way?